# How to implement Hamburger Icon in Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to implement Hamburger Icon in Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage? Now there is a Arrow Icon.

Comment: You need to add some code to see what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to use your MasterDetailPage DetailPage with NavigationPage:

```net
var masterDetailPage = new MasterDetailPage {
            Master = new MenuPage(),
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new YourHomePage()),
        };
```

Comment: This doesn't add a hamburger icon for me. At least, not with iOS